# Is there a way to parse the "%m" or "%msg" or "%message" in XML?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, log4j

I am working on inserting data into database with log4j.

I want to insert into this simple table with 2 columns:
Col1: ID
Col2: Name

this is in my configuration file

```
<JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="test9" >
  <ConnectionFactory class="log4j2.jdbc" method="getDatabaseConnection" />
  < Column name="id" pattern='%m' />
  < Column name="name" pattern='%m' />
</JDBC>
```

and in my java, I use

```
logger.info("1", "john");
```

no matter what I do, I can only insert like this:

```
Col1: 1
Col2: 1
```

I want to achieve a way to have insert do this:

```
Col1: 1
Col2: john
```

Is this even possible? Like through parsing the %m? or is there any trick behind the pattern design?

Thanks for your effort!!

Comment: %s would be replace with string as used in print_r

Comment: How would I use it on the XML side? would it be %m still for both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself... just in case anybody will be stuck onto this. I highly doubt i'll be the only one using log4j2 logging into database with multiple messages..

so the way to send multiple columns is through ThreadContext: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/ThreadContext.html

it acts like a map, and you can "put" a pair of strings into it.

in the XML pattern side. just get the value by doing %X{key}

for example:

```
ThreadContext.put("id", 1);
ThreadContext.put("name", john);
```

note: must log any message in order to trigger above data to send to db.

configuration:

```
<column name="id" pattern="%x{id}">
<column name="name" pattern="%x{name}">
```